# Exporting Data with a Specific Date

Tags: ms-access

***Scenario:***

I have a single table in access 2007 with few columns and several thousand records which I have imported form a CSV file via a “DoCmd” statement.

***What I want:***

I want to export these records but on a basis of specific field content and with another column’s date basis. i.e. I want to export the records with the “EQ” ( content of a columns field “`SERIES`”) and with a date which is one amongst the many dates the column have.

The “`SERIES`”, I have defined in “`Criteria`” in my query and it is working fine as the “`SERIES`” remains the same every day.

***Issues:***

The problem is with the date that changes every month and I cannot define or hard-code it in anywhere.
Query is working fine with the file where there is no date, but with a date, it is an issue.

***Question:***

Can we put a user define `textbox`, where user can define the date and that date will be taken by the query and will return the records with that defined date? In addition, “`SERIES`” is already defined in query so the result will be exact.

I use the following statement for exporting the data:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "NewFnoSpec", "fnoquery", 
"C:\Users\welcome\Desktop\Output.txt", True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following 'WHERE' clause as a starting point to select records for one specific date:

```
WHERE (((Table1.SERIES)="First") AND ((Table1.MyDate)=#4/4/2014#));
```

You can prompt the user to enter a date by using:

```
WHERE (((Table1.SERIES)="First") AND ((Table1.MyDate)=[Enter Date]));
```

If there was some pattern or rule as to the desired date (i.e. first day of prior month, first Monday of prior month, etc.) you could structure the 'WHERE' clause to handle that without a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply and an answer. Your answer is quite helpful. I have tried a little easier way and it worked for me. I put a text box named txtexpdate,  on the form and in the query ( design mode ), in criteria I have put this :

**Like "*" & [Forms]![Futures]![txtexpdate] & "*"**

This is working fine at this juncture. And thank you once again for your efforts to answer my question. Hope this also will help others as an option to this problem.

Regards
Achal